# Command prompt issue C:\Users is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: cmd

My command prompt is having some issues. C:\Users is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I don't know what the issue is. It was working 5 min previously when I was working in java not it will not recognize anything. The only thing that I did previous to that was to delete off my mysql data directly from the folder.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show the actual command you try to execute?

Comment: is that what you wanted??

Comment: Not really. You should edit the question to include the ***exact*** text you write in the command window. If the exact text you write is `C:\Users` then of course there is no such command, it's a directory. If you want to change to chat directory you should use the `cd` command.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to open the directory? in this case it would be
`cd C:\Users`